# Div class displays in chrome & firefox but not IE

Tags: php, css, internet-explorer, html, hover

Can someone help me take a look at this please, I found this similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353655/div-displays-in-firefox-safari-chrome-etc-but-not-in-internet-explorer)

but I do not understand how it works and what does poly-fill.

Here is the link to my website:

http://mojogobbles.com.sg/cupcake-menu/

Here is my css coding for the div class and also the html/php

**CSS**

```
#f1{
 width: 100px;
 height: 50px;
 left: 370px;
 top: 450px;
 background:black;
 position: absolute;
 opacity:0;
 filter: alpha(opacity=0);
 float: left;
 -webkit-transition: 1s all;
 -moz-transition: 1s all;
 transition: 1s all;
 }
#f1:hover {
 background:url(images/flavours/f1.jpg);
 width: 320px;
 height: 320px;
 opacity:100;
 filter: alpha(opacity=100);
 float: left;
 position: absolute;
 }
```

**HTML/PHP**

```
<div id="f1"></div>
```

The div class is not appearing in IE, please help!

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this:

```
filter: alpha(opacity=1);
```

into

```
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
```

The range for opacity when used inside the Alpha-filter is 0-100 , so your current setting is equal to opacity: 0.01

Comment: Hi i have changed and the div class is appearing now, however :hover element is still not working..

Comment: Sounds like you changed it for `#f1` , but you must change it for `#f1:hover`

Comment: Hi dr molle, I did change it to =100, and now when i mouseover the div class, the image declared won't come up, any idea why ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't user the pseudo class `:hover` on a `DIV`, it's likely that IE will ignore it altogether - try using an `A` tag instead or attaching to the `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` events

Answer (score 0):

If you use `div:hover` code in IE, nothing would happen.

This is because IE only supports the hover psuedo for `<a>` tags.

This is not much of a problem in your case, as it is easy to style links to appear as block elements

```
a { display: block; width: 100px height: 50px; }
a:hover { change color etc here }
```

Otherwise, [Css hover](http://naarvoren.nl/artikel/hover/csshover.htc) htc will help to solve the IE browser issue for `div:hover`. Import the htc like bellow,

```
<!--[if IE]>
<style>
body { behavior:url("/csshover.htc");}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

And for cross browser transition, [css3please tutorial](http://css3please.com/) will help you.

Comment: the :hover-selector is supported not only for a-elements since IE7